# How to send cookies with selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Every time when I run my test first step is log in and than I get to desire page. If run this test often log in operation takes a lot of time.

How can I pass log in operation?

Using Chrome and Firefox drivers, java language.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Create cookies using the [Java API](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#addCookie%28org.openqa.selenium.Cookie%29) as follows:

```
Cookie ck = new Cookie("name", "value");
driver.manage().addCookie(ck);
```

Create cookies using the [Python API](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie) as follows:

```
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'foo', 'value': 'bar'})
```

Comment: Personally I receive **org.openqa.selenium.UnableToSetCookieException**
Unable to set Cookie: no URL has been loaded yet

Comment: You first have to navigate to some page before setting cookies (I know, it's weird)

Comment: Will this work for HTTP Only cookies too? If not, could you help me out..

Answer (score 21):

For those that need to set more detailed information on `Cookie` besides `name` and `value` you can use:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie.Builder("name", "value")
    .domain(".mydomain.com")
    .expiresOn(new Date(2015, 10, 28))
    .isHttpOnly(true)
    .isSecure(false)
    .path("/mypath")
    .build();

driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
driver.manage().addCookie();
```

[manage()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#manage%28%29)

[The Options interface with Cookies](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html)

And Selenium's implementation of [Cookie](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Cookie.html)

Comment: Java code could be as below I think:

Cookie ck = new Cookie("name", "value");
driver.manage().addCookie(ck);

Comment: links are all dead

Comment: This is why just providing links isn't the nicest answer, and quoting the relevant parts to the SO answer is an important step...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following code is working fine-

```
String token = tokenValue.substring(7);
    Cookie name = new Cookie("Token", token);
    driver.manage().addCookie(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies failed to load onto some websites, so, the way I handled this problem was to create a user profile/data folder. My browser then behaves like a regular browser, you wouldn't have to manually store the cookies yourself.

JAVA

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=USER_DATA_PATH");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Python

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={USER_DATA_PATH}") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```