# How to use already opened browser active session in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, session-cookies, browser-cache

Is there any way to inherit a session into webdriver? I did lot of search and know it that selenium does not support connecting to already opened browser. It would be better if i could. But now I have thought about some work around. Actually my application starts with a shortcut file which launch firefox, hit the application URL, made the log in, go to the dashboard and leave for the user to use it. In that case i do not need to work on that opened browser, if i can get that active session only and set it while opening the webdriver with selenium then my purpose is solved. Even its possible manually also. As selenium always open incognito webdriver window, i am unable to get that session there. Can any one tell me how to get that session from already opened browser and use it in webdriver? Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might look at serializing your webdriver instance in order to re-use it.

Comment: No its not like that. The previous session was noy activated by webdriver. It was done by some different tool. Which launches the browser, made login and left for user. Suppose I'm doing the same thing manually.Once login done manually then I'm initializing driver = new FirefoxDriver() and want to set that already opened session here in webdriver so that if I hit the URL in webdriver, it do not show me the login page and directly launches the home page. That is what i desire.

Comment: I think you can try to use cookies http://stackoverflow.com/a/10352106/2504101

Comment: @olyv - I think this is the way how i should add cookie. but in this case i have two questions. 1. before adding the cookie, i need to get the same from the opened browser and how to do that? 2. Is this really happen by cookie adding??? I think session is also involved in picture. Only adding cookie will not solve the purpose. kindly correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @souvik 1. You can view cookie in FireFox -> Settings -> Privacy -> remove Individual cookies and there get value of cookie. 2. At least you can try :) And let me suggest one more option to reuse instance of browser http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/7015/6194

Comment: @olyv - Thanx for your precious comments but these are really not working and each time i'm hitting the URL in webdriver, I'm getting the login page back...it means no session has been inherited..feeling really helpless......

Comment: Any Help guys?? m still waiting for the same issue to be resolved...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is just a server which accepts http requests using the json wire protocol. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol
It's an http API.

Each call in the json wire protocol adds a sessionId parameter to the request.

So if you start a session using a driver, you can save that session ID and then instantiate a new driver object and give it the sessionId from before.

If the selenium server is still running that session, then it has no idea which driver object you are using when you send in a request. Feel free to have 100 drivers all with the same sessionID at the same time! :D