# Login using selenium

Tags: selenium

The Basic Scenario is, I've a website `example.com`, here in general, if I log into this website with my credentials,it will redirect to `example.com/example1` page, and with this open if i open a new window or a tab in same browser and enter `example.com`, I'm redirected automatically to `example.com/example1` without asking for any credentials.

Now my question is with selenium, here I'm trying to do the same, but the page is always redirected to `example.com`and asking for credentials though i'm logged in.

please let me know how can i skip this. I'm using the below code in my script.

```
fd.get("http://example.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        if (!fd.getCurrentUrl()
                .equals("http://example1.com")) {
            login(fd);
        }
```

My Login Method

```
private static void login(FirefoxDriver fd) {
        fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='myname']")).sendKeys(
                "userId");
        fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='passWord']")).sendKeys("passWord");
        fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Logon']")).click();
    }
```

Comment: This is because when you start a new `WebDriver` it is not keeping any existing cookies or any session values etc. It depends on what your login system expects e.g. Verification cookie or some sort of session-state value

Comment: @JamieRees, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you just call your Login code every time you navigate to the website?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a new instance of example.com, selenium opens it with new instance of the browser. In order to preserve your login session, open your example.com using existing session. Here's how to do start a new browser tab without destroying your session -

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
driver.get('example.com');
```

Another solution would be to open a new web driver instance with existing session. [more info to attach an existing session](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3927) and [sample of it](https://gist.github.com/DylanLacey/f23e6fceada917dd4f5b). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem by using cookies..

Here is an example: [How to send cookies with selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers