# Issue in cookies in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

What i am trying to do is to save cookies in a file and reusing that cookies for avoiding login every-time,but i am facing error is that

> [org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException: You may only set cookies for the current domain]

Below I am attaching my code.
[CODE FOR READING THE COOKIES]

```
public static WebDriver driver; 

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException                  
{       

    driver=new FirefoxDriver();     
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/#identifier");


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);                 

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Email']")).sendKeys("<<USERNAME>");                         
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='next']")).click();    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Passwd']")).sendKeys("<<PASSWORD>>");   
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();                    


    File file = new File("Cookies.data");                           
    try     
    {       
        // Delete old file if exists
        file.delete();      
        file.createNewFile();           
        FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);                            
        BufferedWriter Bwrite = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);                          
        // loop for getting the cookie information      
        for(Cookie ck : driver.manage().getCookies())



        {       
            Bwrite.write((ck.getName()+";"+ck.getValue()+";"+ck.getDomain()+";"+ck.getPath()+";"+ck.getExpiry()+";"+ck.isSecure()));                                                                                                    
            Bwrite.newLine();   
            System.out.println(ck.getExpiry());
        }       
        Bwrite.flush();         
        Bwrite.close();         
        fileWrite.close();          
    }catch(Exception ex)                    
    {       
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }       
}           
}
```

[CODE FOR USING THAT COOKIES]

```
public  static WebDriver driver;                
public static void main(String[] args)                  
{                           
    driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 

    try{            

        File file = new File("Cookies.data");                           
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);                           
        BufferedReader Buffreader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);                         
        String strline;         
        while((strline=Buffreader.readLine())!=null){                                   
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(strline,";");                                   
            while(token.hasMoreTokens()){                   
                String name = token.nextToken();                    
                String value = token.nextToken();                   
                String domain = token.nextToken();                  
                String path = token.nextToken();                    
                Date expiry =  null;                    

                String val;         
                if(!(val=token.nextToken()).equals("null"))
                {       
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
                    expiry =  df.parse(val); 
                }       
                Boolean isSecure = new Boolean(token.nextToken()).                              
                        booleanValue();     

                Cookie ck = new Cookie(name,value,domain,path,expiry,isSecure);     

                driver.manage().addCookie(ck);
                System.out.println(ck.getDomain());
                System.out.println(ck);
            }       
        }       
    }catch(Exception ex){                   
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }       
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/#identifier");  
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send cookies with selenium webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

In the read cookies java class include a line (copy-paste) immediately after the driver instantiation to call the page as you have done at the end -  `driver.get(https://accounts..........`

This allows the cookies to be set as if they are from the same domain.

Comment: I have tried your approach but still getting the same error.

Comment: to be more clear:  You can only get/set cookies for the current browsing context’s active document.  This means you *must* navigate to a page from the domain before attempting to get/set associated cookies.