# Webdriver JS: How to avoid logging in for every test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a long page with many forms to fill out, that I am breaking up into separate page objects to call for tests. Getting to that page requires a long login process and navigation to that page. Is there some way to avoid having to go through this long logging in process? Is there a way to spin up a regular chrome browser with my cookies, etc?

I am using the latest Webdriver for Node JS, and therefore need a javascript solution for those bindings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send cookies with selenium webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: That is for Selenium Java, which doesn't work. This is explicitly asking for a Webdriver JS solution for the node JS bindings.

Comment: The point was that you can set cookies without Selenium. Have you googled how to create cookies using node.js? It should be a pretty straightforward process.