# How to set a browser cookie when writing tests with Geb and Spock

Tags: selenium-webdriver, spock, geb

I have a quick question.  I am a newcomer to Geb and Spock.  I'm excited to have a chance to learn some more about both of them.

The initial problem I'm faced with is how can I add a cookie (or some other means) in order to dismiss a help walk-through that first appears when the application under test first runs using Geb+Spock?

Any ideas you might have on this would be great.  In order to use some 
when and then blocks, etc... I first have to dismiss the walk-through. 
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

Geb is build on top of selenium webdriver, so this applies as well: [How to send cookies with selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver)

```
import geb.spock.GebSpec

class GebCookieSpec extends GebSpec {

    def setup() {
        Cookie ck = new Cookie("name", "value");
        browser.driver.manage().addCookie(ck);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting.  Thanks for taking a little time out.