# How to pass cookies to local html file while rendering the file through selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Need to pass cookies to the html file in selenium webdriver.

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            '/Users/ddh/Desktop/chromedriver')

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get("file:///Users/ddh/Desktop/text.html")

driver.add_cookie({'name': 'session', 'value': "12345678"})

This is not working.

Comment: Try this example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send cookies with selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it add cookie and print it:

```
driver.get("Your URL");
//add a cookie 
Cookie name = new Cookie("cookie_test", "4343543");
driver.manage().addCookie(name);

Set<Cookie> cookiesList =  driver.manage().getCookies();
//print the cookie
for(Cookie getcookies :cookiesList) {
System.out.println(getcookies );
```

Make sure to import this package `import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;`

Comment: I need to pass cookies to html file

Comment: add your html Url in the get method