# How to open a browser with the help of selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, cookies, web-testing

I want to write by means of selenium (java) automatic login to the website. However every time while, script opens browser (Firefox), data from previous session are deleted. It is for me adverse, because this website requires confirm code SMS.

In browser which I use everyday do not have to confirm the SMS.

Is the solution to this problem?

Sorry for my English

EDit:

I dont know how to add cookie. I found such code:

```
Cookie ck = new Cookie("name", "value");
driver.manage().addCookie(ck);
```

Here (name and value) should enter data existing cookie? I should download cookie with my browser and attach file to my project folder?

Should I create my own cookie?

unfortunately I dont understand this

Comment: You need to add your login-script via cookies/local storage to setUp method (if you are using some unit testing framework). Then when you will run your test -- for each test will be run setUp method.

Comment: something similar to here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Yes, something like this. But it's just to log in using cookies. For the single test, you can use such approach.