# How to get Selenium Webdriver to run on Firefox browser as a different user?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to open an application website on Firefox browser using Selenium Webdriver as a **different user**.

Currently, I am using gecko driver to open that application link, it successfully opens up the browser but unable to open the application link.

But I am able to achieve the same manually by going to Mozilla Firefox icon and clicking on

> "Run as different user"

option (as shown in below image) which further open a popup for user credentials and by entering Username and Password of different user there I am able to open the application link in browser.

[image]

So, is there any way that I can achieve same process using Selenium Webdriver and opens up my application link.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should rather create Firefox profile by running `firefox.exe -p` to launch profile manager. Then you can instantiate firefox web driver implementation and configure it to use given profile.

Are you sure that you want to use pre-configured profile? I find much easier to manage to run drivers in **private/incognito** mode and set cookies manually to configure tests.

Comment: Marcin, I just need to open the website using Selenium webdriver if this can be manageable to run drivers in private/incognito mode and set cookies manually to configure tests then I would like to know your views on it.

Comment: To use incognito mode in firefox web driver see [here](https://gist.github.com/4M01/9b60a5f852fabdc5f65c9496e6eccf03). For how to set cookie look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I have tried this solution but it couldn't help me in opening the link.

Answer (score 0):

You might provide `firefox_binary` as a parameter for the webdriver:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

```
firefox_binary – Instance of FirefoxBinary or full path to the Firefox 
binary. If undefined, the system default Firefox installation will be used.
```

...so, you might use a wrapper script to run firefox as the different user (use `sudo` in Linux).