# How to use the youtube channel cookie with selenium webbdriver?[python]

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I'm studying python selenium, I want to use youtube cookies to log in with selenium webdriver, I don't know much about cookies, can someone help me? YouTube cookies are like this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmKXAnNpYmw)

youtube cookies like this : `CONSENT=YES+VN.vi+20111705121-09-0; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=CfTOOvu1WJec; enabledapps.uploader=0; endscreen-metadata-editor-gh=true; LD_T=8b1711b315170-77f1f-461414-b6f7-ee1e18a9da1443; _ga=GA1.2.618120473.15410733954; 1LD_U=http1s%3A%21F%2Fwww.youtube.com%21Fwatch%3F1v%3DxPS9j3v15mhY; LD_R=; LD_S=true; SID=7gbHHtvqYQ711IphReGQgOLMTEgcx1NAaIf87viSk-4dubQpUFJbizE87dPEjov11e1LXoZnkBQ.; HSID=AkD1id1qtZ411LeExB2cU; SSID=Aq-YAe11JBLKq15SQ_gJ; APISID=f341Us7V1S1Gedbss-W/1AVTybEfggWYK91wLPh; SAPISID=most1J1q3N1P1mHxni/A31rT8t11La04GpArTyd; LOGIN_INFO=AFmmF12swRAIgBdbdG1q0WH11Zm1jTOrzLwBxHZeC11HtAwPIutRKR1T1dZnSx8CIHnVzhOdetO2nBRtFjl1dV4h1ONzBrUo_G1vU1ZR64Izmqg:QUQ3M1jNmeldGUG1R111WnlrMnRUMDcxR1jY1zcHB5bW9vLUVSUEdmRGxRTjdaYTRFcmNa1aHlIdTl1rOUQ5QnRZNVEz1THBkV0R1IVmJm1enZ0TzI4Ri1jRk5aUHRZR2prM3hhSD1dwMTFjR1W5ReFk5TU1N3YnhtVDh0SjJRRlF1MVnR1VdHl3eWVubVpUTmFBWGtWS2lVTlBTaGljU1VXeXVjNjEtYTJ4SXBxeTg0UTh2VlItWDRmUWh6W1lowZFp1WdGZVSjZzcWhPX13VDWEczU3FjYklQMHRQQlVNaGNLVGxCQlZUSkhoX0RMcEpmS1NqaTlo1dU1FjVXV1MVnM2QXc4UQ==; PREF=f1=51000001010&al=en&f5=30&1gl=US; YSC=BBlpMR1dAU9I; _gid=GA1.2.328115581274.154721122145; _fbp=fb.1.1547221121146115.95901816564`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send cookies with selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: sorry Recep Duman, I reply late!

but I don't know about '' name '' and '' value '', the above cookie doesn't have a name and value!