# How do I add and use cookies for a website?

Tags: java, html, selenium, cookies

I am working on an automation software for posting jobpostings.
When I log on through email and password it tells me to fill out a captcha after 4 runs, so I want to use cookies but I cannot get it to work.

I watched a couple of videos but did not understand most of them until I came across this code:

```
    File f = new File("browser.data");
    try{
        f.delete();
        f.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(f);
        BufferedWriter bos = new BufferedWriter(fos);

        for(Cookie ck: driver.manage().getCookies()) {
            bos.write((ck.getName()+";"
            +ck.getValue()+";"
            +ck.getDomain()+";"
            +ck.getPath()+";"
            +ck.getExpiry()+";"
            +ck.isSecure()));
            System.out.println(ck);
            bos.newLine();
        }
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Which works fine for creating a cookie apparently but when I try to use it nothing happens.

This is all of my main, I am a real noob when it comes to selenium and cookies, etc. So I hope somebody here can help me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    driver.get("examplejobpostingsite.com");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login-email-input"))).sendKeys("test@protonmail.com"); //let cookies take over later on
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-password-input")).sendKeys("pass");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-submit-button")).click();

    wait.equals(2);

    File f = new File("browser.data");
    try{
        f.delete();
        f.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(f);
        BufferedWriter bos = new BufferedWriter(fos);

        for(Cookie ck: driver.manage().getCookies()) {
            bos.write((ck.getName()+";"
            +ck.getValue()+";"
            +ck.getDomain()+";"
            +ck.getPath()+";"
            +ck.getExpiry()+";"
            +ck.isSecure()));
            System.out.println(ck);
            bos.newLine();
        }
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when I try 
`driver.manage().getCookieNamed("browser.data")`
Nothing happens, except after 10 seconds I get a timeout because of my WebDriverWait.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352106/7919626

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send cookies with selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I have no problem with creating a cookie, but how do I use that already created cookie in my code to log onto a website automatically? Or does the program do that automatically if the domain stored in the cookie is the one of the website?

Comment: If inserted cookie does not login you automaticaly, it means cookie hasn't be accepted on server side. Check if the cookie still valid after closing browser, after some time duration. Basicaly you need to know the rules for issuing cookies.